# Zero to the zero: undefined?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am seeing some claims on the interwebs that $0^0$ is undefined, but also some claims that it is 1, which makes sense to me in terms of naive set theory:

$$0^0=\emptyset^\emptyset,$$ which is the set of functions from the empty set to itself, and since there is only one such function (viz, the empty function), then $0^0$ must be 1, correct?

Comment: Then it is 1 in set theory and undefined in calculus; there is nothing unusual about it.

Comment: There is no widely accepted convention what $0^0 $ should be. In many cases, it is useful to consider it to be $1$ since it is consistent with many important results